# Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra argument in call

Tags: alamofire, swift3

I have migrated my project to Swift 3 (and updated Alamofire to latest Swift 3 version with `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'` in the Podfile).

I now get an "Extra argument in call" error on every Alamofire.request.  Eg:

```
let patientIdUrl = baseUrl + nextPatientIdUrl
Alamofire.request(.POST, patientIdUrl, parameters: nil, headers: nil, encoding: .JSON)
```

Can anybody tell me why ?

Comment: The error message says, you're passing too many parameters to the request method. The easiest way to help yourself is to look up the actual signature in the documentation.

Comment: Of course I've checked the signature - which is correct. That is the problem. It seems to be Xcode 8 is reporting an invalid error.

Comment: Then retype the method to get the actual syntax with code completion. I suspect the second parameter needs a label.

Comment: It gives exactly the same error with or without the label.

Comment: Does Xcode show a little triangle (^) on that line to tell you which argument is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, it is the url (2nd) parameter.

Comment: So is the URL valid, did you print it to check?

Comment: Yes, the url is valid, but it is a compile time error.

Comment: The first argument is of type URL and the second is HTTPMethod

Comment: @vadian Thanx. I checked my parameter. Now its work for me.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

According to [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) documentation for version 4.0.0 URL request with **HTTP** method would be followings:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get") // method defaults to `.get`    
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/put", method: .put)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/delete", method: .delete)
```

So your url request will be:

```
Alamofire.request(patientIdUrl, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

and a sample request will be:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [AUTH_TOKEN_KEY : AUTH_TOKEN])
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
        print(response.response as Any) // URL response
        print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it working? I am still getting the error of extra parameter in call while using this also
`Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, headers: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Comment: Do you mean
`Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: nil, headers: nil)`

or this `Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: nil)`

there are still errors.

Even this line shows the same error
`Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, headers: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Comment: are you using Alamofire version 4.0.0 & can you remove optional sign (!) from url ?

Comment: Alamofire is the latest one i.e 4.0.0 and optional has nothing to do with extra parameter. As URL returns an optional, so we have to unwrap it.
Are you sure the line written by you in answer `Alamofire.request(patientIdUrl, method: .post, parameters: nil, headers: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)` is working?

Comment: works for me without encoding param, I am using as followings: `Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: dict, headers: header)`

Comment: Well this worked
`Alamofire.request("http//yourserviceURL.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }
    }`

Comment: Cheers!! ... :D

Comment: No need to remove the encoding parameter. Check my answer

Comment: @Abdullah Md.Zubair,@Rajan Maheshwari i tried with your above answers still am getting extra arguement in call issue my code is func POST(url _url: String, params: [String : AnyObject]) -> Future<JSON, NSError> {let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, self.buildAppUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.JSON, headers: self.requestHeaders())}.Thanks

Comment: @Vinathynvr try as followings: Alamofire.request(self.buildAppUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.requestHeaders())
        .responseJSON { response in
            
        }

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair now am getting extra argument method in call error.

Comment: Alamofire.request("", method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
            .responseJSON { response in
                
        }
this works on my side, make sure you are getting proper values from your methods like self.buildAppUrl, params & self.requestHeaders()

Comment: url must be of type `String`.

Answer (score 72):

This one worked for me. 
No need to remove **encoding** parameter

**Update for Swift 5.x**

Alamofire uses the `Result` type introduced in **Swift 5**.
Also `Alamofire.request` has been changed to `AF.request` which will now read their switch `response.result` value with `.success` and `.failure`

```
AF.request("https://yourServiceURL.com", method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ["":""]).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case let .success(value):
            print(value)
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.x / 4.x**

```
Alamofire.request("https://yourServiceURL.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }
    }
```

and make sure that the **parameters** are of type

```
[String:Any]?
```

In case of **Get**

```
Alamofire.request("https://yourGetURL.com", method: .get, parameters: ["":""], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }
    }
```

Even works with

```
JSONEncoding.default
```

**For Headers**

If you are passing headers, make sure their type should be `[String:String]`

Go through the `Parameter Encoding Link`
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol

Comment: @jimijon Its the same as post. Check my updated answer and try any get URL. Leave the parameters blank as `["":""]`

Comment: Ok, just a "red herring" in the error. If any of the other parameters, headers et are wrong, then it gives this weird error.

Comment: Haven't tried with wrong headers. Will give a try and let you know

Comment: Please, can you add a link to Alamofire documentation in which you have see that? I could only find this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#json-encoding that always say: `Extra argument in call`

Comment: @Error404
Read the section `Parameter Encoding Protocol` in the documentation where they have stated everything and the type of parameters should be `[String:Any]`. My error of extra argument call was because of parameter passed as `AnyObject`.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol

Comment: Yes, I have read the section that you linked before but I cannot find where all kind of parameters I can choose. For example, method, encoding as you used in your function.

Comment: @Error404 Encoding depends on the type of API is made at server end. If it accepts post parametes not as raw form, then you have to use `URLEncoding.default`. If it accepts post parameters as raw form, then you have to choose `JSONEncoding.default`
In `GET` you don't need any of them.
If it accepts paramters as form data multipart form, then you have to use the `multipart` feature of alamofire

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! :) I could not find that info before

Comment: The order of parameters is important. it must be: method, parameters, encoding, headers.

Comment: @ricardokrieg What are you talking about? Did you see anything wrong here?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari sorry, I meant the order of arguments (for Alamofire.request call). It must be exactly like you did.

Comment: @ricardokrieg ok, thanks for the appreciation. Can I get a +1 for that :)

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I'm using the latest swift and alamofire, if you get a chance could you take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41484477/nsmutableurlrequest-in-router-class-swift-3

Comment: This answer explains it perfectly. Also, the order in which the parameters are to be listed under the Alamofire.request method is very crucial. For example (URL,methods,parameters,encoding,headers). Any change in this order will lead to an error.

Comment: You are right,headers should be [String:String].Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> **Post method Alamofire 4.0 with Swift 3.0 and xCode 8.0**

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: PARAMS)
                            .responseJSON { closureResponse in
                        if String(describing: closureResponse.result) == "SUCCESS"
                        { 
                           // Sucess code  
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                           // Failure Code 
                        }
                 }
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution is if you are using headers, its type must be [String:String].

Answer (score 2):

This error is up to parameters value. It has to be [String: String]

```
let url = URL(string: "http://yourURLhere")!

    let params: [String: String] = ["name": "oskarko", "email": "youremail@here.com", "sex": "male"]



    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200..<600).responseJSON() { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            var result = [String:String]()

            if let value = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value) 

            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("RESPONSE ERROR: \(error)")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the same problem as you have. The problem is I have imported Alamofire in the header, so I just remove the Alamofire when call request. Like that:

> request(.POST, patientIdUrl, parameters: nil, headers: nil, encoding:
>   .JSON)

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same **Extra argument 'method' in call** error when my **URL variable was out of scope**.

In your case, please make sure both `baseUrl` and `nextPatientIdUrl` are in scope when they are being used `Alamofire.request(patientIdUrl,..)` method.

Hopefully this resolves your issue. Thanks You!

Answer (score 1):

```
func API()
{
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        let headers = ["Vauthtoken":"Bearer \(apiToken)"]
        print(headers)
        //            let parameter = ["iLimit":"10","iOffset":"0","iThreadId":"1"]
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.showSVProgressHUD(text: "Loding...")
        Alamofire.request(ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.API(Join: "vehicle/CurrentVehicleLists"), method:.get, parameters:nil, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
                let dictVal = response.result.value
                let dictMain:NSDictionary = dictVal as! NSDictionary
                let statusCode = dictMain.value(forKey: "status") as! Int
                if(statusCode == 200)
                {

                }
                else if statusCode == 401
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.dismissSVProgressHUD()
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.showErrorMessage(Title: "Internet Connection", SubTitle: "Internet connection Faild", ForNavigation: self.navigationController!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working.

For GET Request

```
Alamofire.request("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1/get").responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value!)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }

    }
```

For POST

```
let parameters = NSDictionary(object: "nara", forKey: "simha" as NSCopying)

    Alamofire.request("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters as? Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in


        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value!)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break

        }
    }
```

Thanks @**Rajan Maheswari**.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with:

1. Reorder parameters (url then method type).
2. Change Encoding Enum to be "JSONEncoding.default" for example.

Note that: Alamofire methods signature change in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I found worth noting.

1. Remove the first url label before its value. Use
   `Alamofire.request("https://yourServiceURL.com", method: .post,`
   instead of `Alamofire.request(url: "https://yourServiceURL.com",
   method: .post,`.
2. Make sure the data type of the parameters is `[String:
   String]`. Declare it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I copy this  code from Alamofire,create a URLRequest and used Alamofire.request(URLRequest)  method, avoid this error

```
originalRequest = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
let encodedURLRequest = try encoding.encode(originalRequest!, with: parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue this way:

Just remove extra parameters, just `parameters`, `encoding` and `headers`, if these parameters are nil you can remove then and leave this way,

```
Alamofire.request(yourURLString, method: .post)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added Alamofire files locally then don't use "Alamofire" before request

```
let apipath = “your api URL”    
    request(apipath, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                do {
                    let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data! as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))

                    guard let JSONDictionary: NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
                        print("Not a Dictionary")
                        return
                    }

                    print("Post Response : \(JSONDictionary)")
                }
                catch let JSONError as NSError {
                    print("\(JSONError)")
                }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                print("failure Http: \(String(describing: response.result.error?.localizedDescription))")
                break
            }
    }
```