# Extra argument in 'method' in call

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
let playlistUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems")!

let params = ["key":API_KEY,"part":"snippet","playlistId":PLAYLIST_ID]

Alamofire.request(playlistUrl, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Please check you xcode version to use Alamofire 4. It should be 8.1+.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 and Alamofire 4**
The thing which you are doing wrong is passing a NSURL as the first argument. Don't pass that as a URL, pass it as a string instead. Also you are doing the wrong encoding here.

So the modified code will be as follows:-

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

The result here is unused. So take the result in a closure.

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData { (response:DataResponse<Data>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(data)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break
        }

}
```

Also do check the encoding required. Check this link for more details.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol

Also check this answer posted by me.
[Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra parameter in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-parameter-in-call/39512635#39512635)

`JSONEncoding.default` or `URLEncoding.default` totally depends on the type of API architecture made at backend.

Answer (score 0):

for alamofire 4,

```
Alamofire.request(playlistUrl, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

Hope this will help you.

For more about latest change in alamofire visit,

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol

Comment: This will give the same error as playlistURL is not a string here and a URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

**//Correct code is:**

```
let playlistUrl = NSURL(string: 
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems")!

let params:Parameters = 
["key":API_KEY,"part":"snippet","playlistId":PLAYLIST_ID]

Alamofire.request(playlistUrl, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: 
params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil)
```