# Alamofire 4, Swift 3 and building a json body

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swift3, alamofire

```
{"title":"exampleTitle","hashTags":[{"name":"tag1"},{"name":"tag2"}],"uploadFiles":
[{"fileBytes":"seriesOfBytes\n","filename":"upload.txt"}]}
```

That is my desired body I want to send to the backend.

I'm using Swift 3.0 and Alamofire 4 and i have multiple questions.

**first**, How do i correctly create a body which contains values and arrays of values?

My approach is:

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
para.setValue("exampleTitle", forKey: "title")
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
print(jsonString)
```

which gives me

```
{"title":"exampleTitle"}
```

**second**, my alamofire .post request looks like the following and is not working:

```
Alamofire.request(postURL, method: .post, parameters: jsonString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

i get the error message: extra argument 'method' in call. If i instead of jsonString use a string of the type

```
 var jsonString: [String : Any]
```

it does work, but i do not know how to put the body into this type.

**summary**
looking for help (example would be the best) on how to create the body, and how to send it via Alamofire 4 and swift 3 to my backend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST request with BODY in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982513/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-body-in-swift)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to pass parameter as `[String:Any]` dictionary, so create one dictionary as your passing JSON like this.

```
let params = [ 
                "title":"exampleTitle",
                "hashTags": [["name":"tag1"],["name":"tag2"]],
                "uploadFiles":[["fileBytes":"seriesOfBytes\n","filename":"upload.txt"]]
             ]
```

Now pass this `params` as parameter in Alamofire request.

```
Alamofire.request(postURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: one more question before i mark it as accepted: i have headers too, where do i place them in the request and how do they need to be formatted? i tried  to add them like parameters but it gave me the extra call message again.

Comment: For header check this one https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers, if you still not get ask new question here.

Comment: Check this for passing header http://stackoverflow.com/a/39512635/6433023

Comment: The key is the encoding: JSONEncoding.default