# Why am I unable to do a simple Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

We are trying to get our iOS application to connect to our server.
We are using `Swift 3.0.2` and `Alamofire 4.4.0`.
Every time I try to make an `Alamofire.request`, I get an error saying `Extra argument in call`.

I have looked online at various pages and articles including ones on Stack Overflow and have tried all sorts of troubleshooting techniques such as rearranging the terms inside the call, initializing the values outside the call etc.
All we are trying to do is send a specific number to our server every time a specific button is pressed (The buttons and numbers are synced, so when we press button 1, we want to send a '1' to the server, and so on).
Any help on how to proceed further?

[image: Alamofire Error]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `AlamoFire.request` takes a `String` rather than a `NSURL` as an argument.  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-methods

Comment: You should add the code as a code snippet instead of photo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra parameter in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-parameter-in-call)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the latest **cocoapods** . To check latest **pod** type **pod --version** in terminal and make sure its **1.2.0**. Even you downloaded the latest **Alamofire4** with cocoapods, if your cocoapods is not latest it sometimes download previous version of **Alamofire**. Check this first, after that use this format :

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: yourParameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { (response) in


    }
```