# How to pass JSON object in Alamofire request swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire, put

I am doing service calls using `Alamofire` API. So far `GET` methods are working fine. And now I need to do a `PUT` request. Also it is accepting body parameters in this type.

```
{
"LeaveEntryCode":0,
"RequestId":0,
"EmployeeCode":17227,
"LeaveYear":2017,
"LeaveTypeCode":1,
"LeaveReasonCode":1,
"BaseType":"ess",
"StartDate":"2017-06-16T00:00:00",
"EndDate":"2017-06-16T00:00:00",
"NoOfDays":1.0,
"StartDateSession":"full",
"EndDateSession":"full",
"PreApproved":false,"ForDate":"1901-01-01T00:00:00",
"Remarks":"I have to attend for a wedding of my close relatives",
"CoveringPersonCode":0,
"RequestStatus":"P",
"Deleted":false,
"Status":false,
"CreatedBy":0,
"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"UpdatedBy":0,
"UpdatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"DeletedBy":0,
"DeletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"ModuleId":2,
"ObjectId":20,
"StartDateString":"06/16/2017",
"EndDateString":"06/16/2017",
"LeaveDayList":["06/16/2017-FH,06/16/2017-SH"],
"SystemLeaveTypeCode":"ANN",
"LeaveTypeName":"ANNUAL",
"Employee":null,
"LieuDayList":null,
"BaseLeaveType":"ANN",
"CoveringPersonName":"",
"LeaveReasonName":"Personal",
"DocumentSource":"LEAVE",
"AttachedDocument":null
}
```

I created a `[String:Any]` object and assigned to `parameters` in the following request.

> But I got an error called Extra argument 'method' in the call.

But If I assigned it as `["":""]` that error disappears. How can I solve this? Please help me.

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headerToken)
```

**UPDATE**

```
var dictionary:[String:String]!
dictionary=[
            "LeaveEntryCode":"0",
            "RequestId":dm.strReqID,
            "EmployeeCode":dm.strEmpCode,
            "LeaveYear":dm.selectedYear,
            "LeaveTypeCode":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
            "BaseType":"ess",
            "StartDate":dm.startDate,
            "EndDate":dm.endDate,
            "NoOfDays":dm.noOFDays,
            "StartDateSession":dm.startDateSession,
            "EndDateSession":dm.endDateSession,
            "RequestStatus":"P",
            "PreApproved":"0",
            "ForDate":"01/01/1901",
            "Remarks":comment,
            "CoveringPersonCode":dm.strcoveringPersonCode,
            "LeaveDayList":strDayLvList,
            "BaseLeaveType":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
            "LeaveReasonCode":dm.selectedReasontypeCode,
            "AttachedDocument":"null"
            ]
```

Comment: Show the declaration of your `parameters` dictionary

Comment: Change the declaration to `[String:Any]` from `[String:String]` means `var dictionary:[String:Any]!`

Comment: do I need to convert that into json as well,, because I tried in rest client it didnt accept when there is [ ] instead of {}

Comment: I'm just saying to change the declaration to `[String:Any]` dictionary from the `[String:String]` dictionary, `[String:Any]` is still a dictionary not the array.

Comment: @user1960169 what is the type for 'method' that you use in Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headerToken) ?

Comment: @AravindAR Its a HTTPMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameters should be of `Parameters` type not dictionary.

try this:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
                "LeaveEntryCode":"0",
                "RequestId":dm.strReqID,
                "EmployeeCode":dm.strEmpCode,
                "LeaveYear":dm.selectedYear,
                "LeaveTypeCode":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
                "BaseType":"ess",
                "StartDate":dm.startDate,
                "EndDate":dm.endDate,
                "NoOfDays":dm.noOFDays,
                "StartDateSession":dm.startDateSession,
                "EndDateSession":dm.endDateSession,
                "RequestStatus":"P",
                "PreApproved":"0",
                "ForDate":"01/01/1901",
                "Remarks":comment,
                "CoveringPersonCode":dm.strcoveringPersonCode,
                "LeaveDayList":strDayLvList,
                "BaseLeaveType":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
                "LeaveReasonCode":dm.selectedReasontypeCode,
                "AttachedDocument":"null"
                ]
```

Comment: when I dont want to pass body parameters how can I pass a null or empty value? when it was [String:String] I passed as ["":""] when I dont want to pass those parameters. Can you pplease let me know?

Comment: if you don't want to send body param create body param as - `let bodyParams : Parameters = [:]` and pass `bodyParams` . You can do the same for 'headerParams'  as well.

Comment: [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1.1 23.99.116.70:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count I am getting this in my log after I changed into [:] this is another method that I dont need to send body params :(

Comment: in response/error are you getting this or this is server side logs?

Comment: That's great! if my answer helped you, Accept it. Happy Coading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146613/discussion-between-user1960169-and-suryakant).

Answer (score 2):

You got an error called Extra argument 'method' in call which is due to headers,

Try passing headers as nil or as follows :

```
//Here param equals to your dictionary as [String :Any]

//Pass Headers as Dictionary as well.

     Alamofire.request("", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:["" : ""])
```

It Worked for me.

Check this link as well: 
   [Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra parameter in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-parameter-in-call)

Comment: But I need to pass some headers as well

Answer (score 1):

> //try this
>   
>   `Alamofire.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters as! Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headerToken)`

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameters of type `[String:AnyObject]?` and depending on whether you need parameters or not assign value to it or set it as `nil`. For headers make it of type `[String:AnyObject]?`. So if you don't have header make it `nil`. For example
var dictionary:[String:String]?

```
if shouldAddParams{
dictionary=[
            "LeaveEntryCode":"0",
            "RequestId":dm.strReqID,
            "EmployeeCode":dm.strEmpCode,
            "LeaveYear":dm.selectedYear,
            "LeaveTypeCode":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
            "BaseType":"ess",
            "StartDate":dm.startDate,
            "EndDate":dm.endDate,
            "NoOfDays":dm.noOFDays,
            "StartDateSession":dm.startDateSession,
            "EndDateSession":dm.endDateSession,
            "RequestStatus":"P",
            "PreApproved":"0",
            "ForDate":"01/01/1901",
            "Remarks":comment,
            "CoveringPersonCode":dm.strcoveringPersonCode,
            "LeaveDayList":strDayLvList,
            "BaseLeaveType":dm.selectedLeaveTypeCode,
            "LeaveReasonCode":dm.selectedReasontypeCode,
            "AttachedDocument":"null"
            ]
} else {
dictionary = nil
}
```