# Extra argument in .request call -- Alamofire + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a `.request()` call using Alamofire 4 and Swift 4. Here's the code I'm using:

```
static func getPlaceData(url: String, parameters: [String: String]) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let json: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(json)
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

where `headers` is:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer /*PRIVATE KEY*/"
]
```

I am getting the following error:
*Extra argument 'method' in call*,  at the `Alamofire.request(...` line.

I've read through quite a few SO posts about similar issues but none of their solutions have fixed my problem:

- [Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra argument in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-argument-in-call)
- [Swift Alamofire Request Error - Extra Argument in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704860/swift-alamofire-request-error-extra-argument-in-call)

I've also read in the [this documentation guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#parameter-encoding-protocol) and [this issues thread on GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508) but neither have solved the issue.

What is the proper syntax for a `.request()` call with required `parameters` and `headers`?

The code is for making an authenticated call from Swift code using the Yelp Fusion API -- maybe someone can suggest a better method than Alamofire?

Comment: Can you pls try changing or casting parameters to [String: Any]

Comment: @Aakash tried casting to `[String: Any]` and I had the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, no thanks to any documentation or GitHub threads.

The logic in the above code snippet (from the question) referenced a constant called `headers`, which was declared outside of `getPlaceData(url:parameters:)`. This is because in order to access the Yelp Fusion API you need to include an extra field in the `HTTP` header you send to include the private API key using the format mentioned [here](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication).

I moved the `headers` data structure inside of `getPlaceData(url:parameters:)` and it fixed the issue, so my resulting function is as follows:

```
static func getPlaceData(url: String, parameters: [String: String]) {
  let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Bearer /*PRIVATE KEY*/"
  ]

  Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: 
  JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    if response.result.isSuccess {
      let json: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
      print(json)
    } else {
      print("error")
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why this fixed the issue, but the code works now.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the documentations and found out two things

1. The request method signature which is

   ```
    public func request(
       _ url: URLConvertible,
       method: HTTPMethod = .get,
       parameters: Parameters? = nil,
       encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
       headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
       -> DataRequest
   ```

[Link to the documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift#L132)

2. The `Parameter` typeAlias is a type of `[String:Any]` where as you are passing `[String:String]` which is conflicting.

[Link to the Parameter Definition in the DOC](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/0456f5b501f46591a77b4bb6f2e2e2a97d095042/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L44)

So all you need to do it change the signature and you are good.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, tried this to no avail -- see my answer for what worked for me